# multi pv mode in GUI

Tags: engines, software

is their any facility in babas chess (4.0) to facilitate multi pv mode. babas chess that i have only shows single pv. if it doesn't then which GUI (free) has facility for the multi pv mode running for pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't use Babas chess, I'm sure Chessbase and Arena support multi-pv.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Babaschess engine configuration:

[image: Multi-PV configuration in Bababaschess 4.0]